# I am trying to play an audio file and it doesnt work Objective C IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi I am trying to play an audio file, but it doesn't work for some reason. I dont get any errors so i assume it must work but my audio doesn't play can u help me pls

```
NSString *path = @"%@/Elevator.mp3";
NSString *soundFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:path,[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
NSLog(soundFilePath);

AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];
player.numberOfLoops = 1; //Infinite

[player play];
```

I do have this line constantly in my console

```
skipping input stream 0 0 0x0
```

Comment: I edited my answer so check my answer now.It works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating class attribute for a player:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *player;
```

And then use it to play sound. Otherwise, your player will be deallocated right after the method where it was created finishes executing.

Answer (score 0):

I created sample one for your question.It plays audio successfully now.

I forgot to say this.First set

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVKit/AVKit.h>  //For AVPlayerViewController
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>  //For AVAudioPlayer
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic,strong)AVAudioPlayer *player; 
- (IBAction)actionPlayAudio:(id)sender;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@end
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize player;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
}
- (IBAction)actionPlayAudio:(id)sender 
{
   NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Elevator" ofType:@"mp3"];
   NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
   player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];
   [player play];
}
@end
```

Comment: Doesnt do anything either

Comment: The thing is i need the audio file to play automaticly not when a button is pressed

Comment: If you want to do that put in viewDidLoad method.

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:yourUrlString]];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    if (data) {
         [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(upadateCurrentTrack:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:NO];
    }

}];

[task resume];

-(void)upadateCurrentTrack:(NSData *)data {
AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data  error:NULL];
audioPlayer.delegate = self;
[audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
[audioPlayer play];
```

}